# Boxplot and Barchart shifted when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, boxplot

I'm trying to align a barplot and a boxplot but when I do so, the boxplot is basically shifted along the x-axis.
This is my previous code:

```
d = {"1":[140,118], "2":[133,111], "3":[111, 86]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
x = df["1"]
y = df["2"]
z = df["3"]
columns =[x, y, z]
l=["top", "middle", "bottom"]
ice_val = [140, 133, 111]
withoutice_val = [118, 111, 86]

x = np.arange(len(l))
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
r1 = ax.bar (x - width/2, ice_val, width, label="with ice-activity")
r2 = ax.bar (x + width/2, withoutice_val, width, label="without ice-activity")
ax1=ax.twinx()
ax1.boxplot(columns)
ax1.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax.set_xticks(x)

plt.show()
```

which gives me this result:

[resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxgsG.png)png

There are already some questions with the same problem, but those answers seem to somehow not solve my problem (or I'm simply not experienced enough with Python)..

I really appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Comment: You could set the start value of np.range() to 1 and add 1 to the end value. `x = np.arange(1,len(l)+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.arange
```

starts at 0, you can do

```
x = 1 + np.arange(len(l))
```

Comment: @Lex, I suggest you have a look at seaborn. Much much easier to use than native matplotlib with pandas